# Update Kernel version to 3.19 on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos

I need **kernel version 3.19** on my CentOS 7, currently is it 3.10. 
I know that following steps can be used to update kernel version to the stable latest one.

1. sudo rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
2. sudo rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm

**INSTALLATION**

- sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-lt
- sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
- sudo reboot

But how can I install 3.19 version of kernel ? When I list ***yum list --showduplicates kernel*** from repositories at my system, I can see only 3.10. but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Why you would you like to use an old kernel when there are already updated kernels available? I have followed the instruction to [install latest kernel](https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/)

Comment: Thanks muhammad. But it is the requirement of the application that we are running, those to meet the requirements and run application correctly I have to use Kernel 3.19 even though it is old as you said